# What does it mean when a picture with path that says /internal/

Tags: internal-storage

I'm a 51 year old, and I don't know anything about android. I used to call my kids and take pictures on my phone. What does it mean when a picture with  path that says /internal/ in my device. I have a LG K20 plus lgmp260.

Answer (score 2):

For android device, it comes up with two type of storage type,Internal and External.

Let's have a comparison of these:

**Internal Storage**

- Internal storage is the built-in storage capacity of the device. It cannot be changed. For Example: 4GB, 8GB, 16GB, 32GB, 64GB etc.
- All applications are stored on internal memory by default.
- Internal memory is faster.
- Cannot be removed (static)

**External Storage (micro SD card)**

- The storage space that supplements internal storage. Also comes up with capacity similar to that of internal, 4GB, 8GB, 16GB, 32GB, 64GB, 128GB etc.
- Some app data can be moved to external memory (Example: Camera Photos)
- Slower than internal memory
- Can be removed and add another with higher capacity (portable) *[ Higher capacity also has a specific limit. Say, if a device can add up to 64GB external storage, you cannot add a 128GB storage ]*

**Note: Some android devices support internal storage only. Also, Android version 6.0+ devices have a feature to use micro SD card (external) as internal memory.**

Answer (score 1):

You phone has a built-in storage chip, and a MicroSD card slot. Since the storage chip is forged into your phone, it cannot be removed by normal means. So all apps refer to that storage area as "internal", while the MicroSD card is referred to as "external" for its easy removability.